# Mysql don't want to start

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, authorization

Hello guys i am trying to start mysql. All was working fine before but now when i do :

> service mysqld start

That anwser me :

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service
>   Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

So i did `systemctl status mysqld.service` and "journalctl -xe"

That the answer :

> ● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-10-23 14:28:27 CEST; 4min 47s ago
>        Docs: man:mysqld(8)
>              http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
>     Process: 6943 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>     Process: 6922 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    Main PID: 6943 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>      Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
>       Error: 13 (Permission denied)
>
> Oct 23 14:28:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmtu9.png): Starting MySQL Server...
>   Oct 23 14:28:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmtu9.png): mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Oct 23 14:28:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmtu9.png): mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Oct 23 14:28:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmtu9.png): Failed to start MySQL Server.

I understand anything of that ... need help

Last command that i did was : (if that can help)

> npm install http

And i was doing a tchat with node.js and socket.io

Here more detail that i don't understand ^^ [image: here]

Comment: this is poss off-topic here and better suited for super user || unix SE

Comment: i will change that :)

Comment: "Permission denied" sounds interesting...

Comment: i tryed to run all with sudo but nothing change

Comment: I guess you should to setup ownership by command:
`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: thx a lot @EvgenyA.Mamonov that solve my problem thx a lot i did : 
    sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

Comment: for sure :) thx a lot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check permissions of /var/lib/mysql directory by command

`ls -la /var/lib |grep mysql`

The output should be like this

`drwxr-xr-x  24 mysql         mysql         4096 Aug 25 10:54 mysql`

If you will see

`drwxr-xr-x  24 root         root         4096 Aug 25 10:54 mysql`

Then you should to change ownership by command: 
`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`